# two ways of counting

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm reading Morris DeGroot's Probability and Statistics. In chapter 1.9 there's an example 1.9.3 says that

> suppose that 12 dice are to be rolled. We shall determine the probability $p$ that each of the six different numbers will appear twice.

The answer in the book is that

$$p = \frac{12!}{2^6 \times 6^{12}} = 0.0034$$

But after I learnt Feller's star-and-bar, I thought there should be another way of thinking. That is to put 12 balls into 6 different boxes. Then the answer could be

$$p = \frac{1}{\binom{12+5}{5}} = 0.00016160$$

As the answer numbers are different, my thought should be wrong. But I could not figure it out why I'm wrong.

Comment: The events counted by Stars and Bars are not all equally likely.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Really. Thanks! One more thing, any way to distinguish basic events so that the sample space is simple?

Comment: The standard sample space views the dice as labelled $1$ to $12$, and consists of all sequences $(a_1,\dots,a_{12})$ where the $a_i$ range from $0$ to $6$. This gives a sample space of equally likely outcomes, and we can solve any problem (in principle!)  by counnting.

Comment: 12 balls in 6 boxes doesn't account for the condition about each of the six different numbers appearing twice.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If evey box contains 2 balls, then it will be equal to each number appearing twice.

Comment: But you have counted all the ways of putting 12 balls into 6 boxes, haven't you, not just those where every box gets exactly 2 balls?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is this: There are $N:={12+5\choose5}$ different ways to put $12$ indistinguishable balls into $6$ boxes numbered from $1$ to $6$, and exactly one of these allocations has $2$ balls in each box. Therefore the probability of obtaining this outcome is given by $p={1\over N}$.

But the random mechanism producing this allocation does not choose each of the $N$ allocations with equal probability: The random mechanism has $6^{12}$ equiprobable elementary events. Only $1$ of these puts all balls in the first box, but ${12!\over2^6}=7\,484\,400$ elementary events realize the desired allocation of two balls in each box.